# PyQT - QTableWidget get header labels after dragged/moved columns

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget which I fill with data from SQL - I enabled to reorder the columns in the View by

```
self.horizontalHeader().setSectionsMovable(True)
```

To give the user perfect experience, I created much of code, that the user can decide which column he want to see by two list boxed, one showing the headers already in the table visible, in the other, all headers possible by the SQL Table. The user can switch the columns left an right and make them visible or not. The user can also put the elements in the list up and down to reorder the headers from the column. For the visible column list I have to get a list with all visible headers in the TableWidget -  But I only have one problem:
When the user drags a Header like "ID" to first position

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2xE4.png)

and I want to get all the headers as a list in a for loop,

```
header = self.horizontalHeaderItem(column).text()
```

gives "USERNAME" as first column (position 0) and "ID" as last column (position 3). Also

```
header = self.horizontalHeader().model().headerData(0,Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
```

makes no difference..

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must iterate with logical index

```
header = self.horizontalHeader()
    for col in range(self.columnCount()):
        print(self.horizontalHeaderItem(header.logicalIndex(col)).text())
```